# The XSL template is not working inside of my HTML

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am fairly new to XSLT. I have previously created an HTML page, and decided to incorporate it with XSLT. I made a smaller .XSL file to see if my logic was correct, and the .XML file outputs without any issues. However, when I try that same logic in previous HTML that opened without issue, it does not output anything but the text values. I thought I could use an XSL template in the middle of an HTML file, but maybe I cannot. Lines 46-61 is where I tried to use my same logic from the working .XSL file. 
 I have been viewing the .XSL tree in Internet Explorer and Google Chrome. To show the output, I open the .XML file in Internet Explorer. Here is one .XML file and two .XSL files.

Sample XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="ugh1.xsl"?>

<team name="PeLakers"
location = "Mobile, Alabama"
locationURL = ""
videoURL = ""
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <coach>
    <name>D. Melton</name>
    <height>5'11</height>
  </coach>

  <player>
    <playerImgSource>FC3pQ10.jpg</playerImgSource>
    <name>Lonzo Ball</name>
    <position>Point Guard</position>
    <height>6'7</height>
    <weight>190</weight>
  </player>

  <player>
    <playerImgSource>FC3pQ10.jpg</playerImgSource>
    <name>Brandon Ingram</name>
    <position>Small Forward</position>
    <height>6'8</height>
    <weight>190</weight>
  </player>

  <player>
    <playerImgSource>FC3pQ10.jpg</playerImgSource>
    <name>Kyle Kuzma</name>
    <position>Power Forward</position>
    <height>6'9</height>
    <weight>220</weight>
  </player>
</team>
```

Working .XSL file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">

    <html>

    <body>

        <div style="width:30%; height:30%; overflow:scroll;">
            <xsl:for-each select="team/player">
            <dl>
                <xsl:variable name="x" select="playerImgSource"/>
                <dt><img src='{$x}' alt="Player" style="width:40%; height:40%;" align="left"/></dt>
                    <dd><xsl:value-of select="name"/></dd>
                    <dd>- Position: <xsl:value-of select="position"/></dd>
                    <dd>- Height: <xsl:value-of select="height"/></dd>
                    <dd>- Weight: <xsl:value-of select="weight"/></dd>

            </dl>
            <br/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </div>    

    </body>

    </html>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

.XSL file that does not output correctly

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <html>
    <body>
        <p><span style="font-size:15px; font-family:&quot; Calibri&quot; ,sans-serif;"></span></p>
        <table margin="0" border="1px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="position:absolute; height:100%; width:100%; left:0; right:0; top:0; bottom:0;">
            <tbody>

                <tr>
                  <td colspan="3" style="width:100%; border:1pt solid windowtext; background:gray; padding:0in 5.4pt; height:22.5%; vertical-align:top;">
                  </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                  <td style="width:38%; border-right: 1pt solid windowtext; border-bottom:1pt solid windowtext; border-left:1pt solid windowtext; border-image:initial;border-top:none; background:rgb(112, 48, 160); padding:0in 5.4pt; height:12.5%; vertical-align:top;">
                    <p style="margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;margin-left:0in;line-height:  normal;font-size:15px;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif;"></p>
                  </td>
                  <td rowspan="2" style="width:25%; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:1pt solid windowtext; border-right:1pt solid windowtext; background:rgb(255, 192, 0); padding:0in 5.4pt; height:6.6%; vertical-align:top;">
                    <p style="margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;margin-left:0in;line-height:normal;font-size:15px;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif;text-align:center;"><strong><span style="font-size:50px;">Coach:</span></strong></p>
                    <p style="margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;margin-left:0in;line-height:  normal;font-size:15px;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif;"></p>
                    <p style="margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;margin-left:0in;line-height:  normal;font-size:15px;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif;">
                      <img width="40%" height="18%" src="FC3pQ10.jpg" alt="Coach"/>
                    </p>
                  </td>
                  <td style="width:38%; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:1pt solid windowtext; border-right:1pt solid windowtext; background:rgb(112, 48, 160); padding:0in 5.4pt; height: 12.5%; vertical-align:top;">
                    <p style="margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;margin-left:0in;line-height:  normal;font-size:15px;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif;"></p>
                  </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                  <td rowspan="2" style="width:28.7%; border-right: 1pt solid windowtext;border-bottom: 1pt solid windowtext;border-left: 1pt solid windowtext;border-image: initial;border-top: none;padding: 0in 5.4pt; background:pink; height: 3.8%; vertical-align:top;">
                    <p style="margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;margin-left:0in;line-height:  normal;font-size:15px;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif;"></p>
                    <iframe width="99%" height="95%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xKdVTomBID8" frameborder="50" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"></iframe>
                  </td>
                  <td rowspan="2" style="width: 28.7%; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:1pt solid windowtext; border-right:1pt solid windowtext; padding:0in 5.4pt; background:pink; height:3.8%; vertical-align:top;">
                    <p style="margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;margin-left:0in;line-height:  normal;font-size:15px;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif;"></p>
                    <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3430.9287579053926!2d-88.18186818397758!3d30.692280494630253!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x889bb2a5b86792ad%3A0x79078db3102940d3!2sMitchell%20Center!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1573591584818!5m2!1sen!2sus" width="99%" height="95%" frameborder="50" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
                  </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                  <td rowspan="2" style="width:25%; bborder-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:1pt solid windowtext; border-right:1pt solid windowtext; background:rgb(255, 192, 0); padding: 0in 5.4pt; height: 300.3pt;vertical-align: top;">
                    <p style="margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;margin-left:0in;line-height:normal;font-size:15px;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif;text-align:center;"><strong><span style="font-size:50px;">Players:</span></strong></p>
                    <p style="margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;margin-left:0in;line-height:  normal;font-size:15px;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif;"></p>
                    <xsl:template match="/">
                        <div style="width:30%; height:30%; overflow:scroll;">
                            <xsl:for-each select="team/player">
                            <dl>
                                <xsl:variable name="x" select="playerImgSource"/>
                                <dt><img src='{$x}' alt="Player" style="width:40%; height:40%;" align="left"/></dt>
                                    <dd><xsl:value-of select="name"/></dd>
                                    <dd>- Position: <xsl:value-of select="position"/></dd>
                                    <dd>- Height: <xsl:value-of select="height"/></dd>
                                    <dd>- Weight: <xsl:value-of select="weight"/></dd>

                            </dl>
                            <br/>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </div>    
                    </xsl:template>

                    <p style="margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;margin-left:0in;line-height:  normal;font-size:15px;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif;">
                    </p>
                    <p style="margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;margin-left:0in;line-height:  normal;font-size:15px;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif;"></p>
                    <p style="margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;margin-left:0in;line-height:  normal;font-size:15px;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif;"></p>
                  </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                  <td style="width:38%; border-right:1pt solid windowtext; border-bottom:1pt solid windowtext; border-left:1pt solid windowtext; border-image:initial;border-top: none; background:rgb(112, 48, 160); padding:0in 5.4pt; height: 12.5%; vertical-align:top;">
                    <p style="margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;margin-left:0in;line-height:  normal;font-size:15px;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif;"></p>
                  </td>
                  <td style="width: 38%; border-top:none; border-left:none; border-bottom:1pt solid windowtext; border-right:1pt solid windowtext; background:rgb(112, 48, 160); padding:0in 5.4pt; height:12.5%; vertical-align:top;">
                    <p style="margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;margin-left:0in;line-height:  normal;font-size:15px;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif;"></p>
                  </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                  <td colspan="3" style="width:100%; border-right:1pt solid windowtext; border-bottom:1pt solid windowtext; border-left:1pt solid windowtext; border-image:initial; border-top:none; background:red; padding: 0in 5.4pt;height: 6.3%; vertical-align:top;">
                    <p style="margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;margin-left:0in;line-height:  normal;font-size:15px;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif;"></p>
                  </td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>

    </body>
    </html>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: That second file you have shown is not a valid XSLT stylesheet, you can't put literal result elements like the `html` element as children of the `xsl:stylesheet` root, you need to write some templates where you can then create result elements.

Comment: @MartinHonnen That kind of things would even work with my 'for-each' clause I have?

Comment: Yes, inside of an `xsl:template` you can have any result elements or XSLT instructions, but each `xsl:template` needs to be a child of the stylesheet's root element (i.e. of the `xsl:stylesheet` or `xsl:transform` element). So make that `<xsl:template match="/">` you have a child of `xsl:stylesheet` and put any contents and/or other XSLT instructions in there.

Comment: In the long run, I would suggest to use template matching not only for the document node but also for other elements e.g. use `<xsl:template match="team/player"><dl>...</dl></xsl:template>`, that way in my opinion the XSLT is much more modular and readable. Of cours that requires use of `xsl:apply-templates` in the other templates to keep processing up.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I took time to read on templates yesterday, and they still kind of confuse me. Isn't the template I have in the not working XSL a template of the root since it's the same template I used in the working XSL? Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: The root element of any stylesheet is the `xsl:stylesheet` element (can also be named `xsl:transform` if you like) and any `xsl:template` needs to be a child of that root element e.g. `<xsl:stylesheet ...><xsl:template match="/">..</xsl:template><xsl:template match="team/player">...</xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>`.  See https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#section-Stylesheet-Structure for XSLT 1 or https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#stylesheet-element for XSLT 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after further investigation, the  was an issue in the broken .XSL file. I was also misusing the xsl:template. I broke down the HTML portion of the .XSL file until it was clean. I was then able to create a mock-up design:

Updated XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="fresh.xsl"?>

<team xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <teamInfo>
        <name>New Angeles PeLakers</name>
        <teamImgSource>FC3pQ10.jpg</teamImgSource>
        <locationURL>https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3430.9287579053926!2d-88.18186818397758!3d30.692280494630253!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x889bb2a5b86792ad%3A0x79078db3102940d3!2sMitchell%20Center!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1573591584818!5m2!1sen!2sus</locationURL>
        <videoURL>https://www.youtube.com/embed/xKdVTomBID8</videoURL>
    </teamInfo>

    <pageColors>
        <headerColor>gray</headerColor>
        <teamTitleColor>blue</teamTitleColor>
        <coachTextColor>black</coachTextColor>
        <coachNameColor>red</coachNameColor>
        <coachHeightColor>black</coachHeightColor>
        <coachBackgroundColor>#ffc000</coachBackgroundColor>
        <playerTextColor>black</playerTextColor>
        <playerNameColor>blue</playerNameColor>
        <playerPositionColor>black</playerPositionColor>
        <playerHeightColor>black</playerHeightColor>
        <playerWeightColor>black</playerWeightColor>
        <playerBackgroundColor>#ffc999</playerBackgroundColor>
        <videoTextColor>rgb(255, 192, 0)</videoTextColor>
        <videoBorderColor>rgb(112, 98, 160)</videoBorderColor>
        <videoBackgroundColor>pink</videoBackgroundColor>
        <mapTextColor>rgb(255, 192, 0)</mapTextColor>
        <mapBorderColor>rgb(112, 48, 160)</mapBorderColor>
        <mapBackgroundColor>green</mapBackgroundColor>
        <footerColor>red</footerColor>
    </pageColors>

    <coach>
        <coachImgSource>FC3pQ10.jpg</coachImgSource>
        <name>D. Melton</name>
        <height>5'11</height>
    </coach>

    <player>
        <playerImgSource>FC3pQ10.jpg</playerImgSource>
        <name>Lonzo Ball</name>
        <position>Point Guard</position>
        <height>6'7</height>
        <weight>190</weight>
    </player>

    <player>
        <playerImgSource>FC3pQ10.jpg</playerImgSource>
        <name>Josh Hart</name>
        <position>Shooting Guard</position>
        <height>6'6</height>
        <weight>200</weight>
    </player>

    <player>
        <playerImgSource>FC3pQ10.jpg</playerImgSource>
        <name>Brandon Ingram</name>
        <position>Small Forward</position>
        <height>6'8</height>
        <weight>190</weight>
    </player>

    <player>
        <playerImgSource>FC3pQ10.jpg</playerImgSource>
        <name>Kyle Kuzma</name>
        <position>Power Forward</position>
        <height>6'9</height>
        <weight>220</weight>
    </player>

    <player>
        <playerImgSource>FC3pQ10.jpg</playerImgSource>
        <name>Ivan Zubac</name>
        <position>Center</position>
        <height>7'0</height>
        <weight>250</weight>
    </player>

</team>
```

Updated XSL file with internal CSS included:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">

    <html> 

    <head>

    <style>
        table {
            position:absolute; height:100%; width:100%; left:0; right:0; top:0; bottom:0;
        }

        td.header {
            width:100%; background:<xsl:value-of select="team/pageColors/headerColor"/>; height:22.5%; text-align:center;
        }


        td.videoBorder {
            width:38%; background:<xsl:value-of select="team/pageColors/videoBorderColor"/>; height:1%; text-align:center;
        }

        td.videoContainer {
            width:28.7%; background:<xsl:value-of select="team/pageColors/videoBackgroundColor"/>; height:3.8%;
        }

        td.mapBorder {
            width:38%; background:<xsl:value-of select="team/pageColors/mapBorderColor"/>; height:1%; text-align:center;
        }

        td.mapContainer {
            width:28.7%; background:<xsl:value-of select="team/pageColors/mapBackgroundColor"/>; height:3.8%;
        }

        td.coachContainer {
            width:25%; background:<xsl:value-of select="team/pageColors/coachBackgroundColor"/>; height:100pt; vertical-align:top;
        }

        td.playerContainer {
            width:25%; background:<xsl:value-of select="team/pageColors/playerBackgroundColor"/>; height:400pt; vertical-align:top;
        }

        td.footer {
            width:100%; background:<xsl:value-of select="team/pageColors/footerColor"/>; height:6.3%;
        }

        div.coachContainer {
            width:80%; height:50%; margin-left:2%;
        }

        div.playerContainer {
            width:100%; height:400pt; overflow:scroll;
        }

        h1 {
            line-height:normal; font-size:600%; color:<xsl:value-of select="team/pageColors/teamTitleColor"/>;
        }

        p.coachText {
            line-height:normal;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif;text-align:center; color:<xsl:value-of select="team/pageColors/coachTextColor"/>; font-size:50px;
        }

        p.playerText {
            line-height:normal;font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif;text-align:center; color:<xsl:value-of select="team/pageColors/playerTextColor"/>; font-size:50px;
        }

        p.videoText {
            line-height:normal; font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif; font-size:450%; color:<xsl:value-of select="team/pageColors/videoTextColor"/>;
        }

        p.mapText {
            line-height:normal; font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif; font-size:450%; color:<xsl:value-of select="team/pageColors/mapTextColor"/>;
        }

        dd.coachName {
            color:<xsl:value-of select="team/pageColors/coachNameColor"/>; font-size:250%;
        }

        dd.coachHeight {
            color:<xsl:value-of select="team/pageColors/coachHeightColor"/>; font-size:150%;
        }

        dd.playerName {
            color:<xsl:value-of select="team/pageColors/playerNameColor"/>; font-size:160%;
        }

        dd.playerPosition {
            color:<xsl:value-of select="team/pageColors/playerPositionColor"/>; font-size:130%;
        }

        dd.playerHeight {
            color:<xsl:value-of select="team/pageColors/playerHeightColor"/>; font-size:130%;
        }

        dd.playerWeight {
            color:<xsl:value-of select="team/pageColors/playerWeightColor"/>; font-size:130%;
        }       
    </style>
    </head>

        <table margin="0" border="1px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tbody>

            <tr>
                <td class="header" colspan="3">
                    <h1>
                        The <xsl:value-of select="team/teamInfo/name"/>
                        <xsl:variable name="teamLogo" select="team/teamInfo/teamImgSource"/>
                        <img src='{$teamLogo}' alt="Team Logo" style="width:10%; height:5%; vertical-align:middle;"/> 
                    </h1>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="videoBorder">
                <p class="videoText"><strong>Video:</strong></p>
                </td>
                <td class="coachContainer" rowspan="2">
                    <p class="coachText"><strong>Coach:</strong></p>
                    <div class="coachContainer">
                        <dl><xsl:variable name="coachImg" select="team/coach/coachImgSource"/>
                            <dt><img src='{$coachImg}' alt="Coach" style="width:40%; height:100%;" align="left"/></dt>
                                <dd class="coachName"><b><xsl:value-of select="team/coach/name"/></b></dd>
                                <dd class="coachHeight"> - Height: <xsl:value-of select="team/coach/height"/></dd>      
                        </dl>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="mapBorder">
                    <p class="mapText"><strong>Map:</strong></p>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td rowspan="2" class="videoContainer">
                <br/>
                <xsl:variable name="videoURL" select="team/teamInfo/videoURL"/>
                <iframe width="99%" height="95%" src='{$videoURL}' frameborder="50" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"></iframe>
              </td>
              <td rowspan="2" class="mapContainer">
                <br/>
                <xsl:variable name="locationURL" select="team/teamInfo/locationURL"/>
                <iframe src='{$locationURL}' width="99%" height="95%" frameborder="50" style="border:0;"></iframe>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="playerContainer" rowspan="2">
                <p class="playerText"><strong>Players:</strong></p>
                <div class="playerContainer">
                    <xsl:for-each select="team/player">
                    <dl style="margin-left:2%">
                        <xsl:variable name="playerImg" select="playerImgSource"/>
                        <dt><img src='{$playerImg}' alt="Player" style="width:35%; height:30%;" align="left"/></dt>
                            <dd class="playerName"><b><xsl:value-of select="name"/></b></dd>
                            <dd class="playerPosition"> - Position: <xsl:value-of select="position"/></dd>
                            <dd class="playerHeight"> - Height: <xsl:value-of select="height"/></dd>
                            <dd class="playerWeight"> - Weight: <xsl:value-of select="weight"/> lbs</dd>

                    </dl>
                    <br/><br/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="videoBorder"/>
              <td class="mapBorder"/>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td class="footer" colspan="3">
              </td>
            </tr>

          </tbody>
        </table>
    </html>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```